# Spark 1.6 SQL Windows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data dump of employees as below. I need to identify the employees who are all only having the status 'Continue'. The output I have mentioned below. What is the best approach I can follow for the same in Spark. The input and output are attached here.
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWDCx.png)

**Input**
Emp_Id  Emp_Age Emp_Status  Emp_Name    Date_Updated

1         43    Continue       John       3/3/15 
1         43    Continue       John       3/4/15 
2         35    Continue       Peter      3/5/15 
3         32    Finished       Alaxender  3/6/15 
3         32    Continue       Alaxender  3/7/15 
4         45    Continue       Patrick    3/8/15 
4         45    No Information Patrick    3/9/15

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yWZO.png)

**Output**
Emp_Id  Emp_Age Emp_Status  Emp_Name    Date_Updated

1         43    Continue    John        3/3/15 
1         43    Continue    John        3/4/15 
2         35    Continue    Peter       3/5/15

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just groupBy employee and check the count of 'Continue' vs the total count ?

```
val employees = input
   .groupBy("Emp_Name")
   .agg(
    count("*").as("total_status"),
    count(when(col("Emp_Status") === "Continue",1)).as("total_continues")
    )
    .filter(col("total_status") === col("total_continues"))
    .select("Emp_Name")

//List of employees
val liste = employees.map(x => x.mkString).collect.toList

//Get the final output
val output = input.filter(col("Emp_Name").isin(liste:_*))
```

Comment: It works @tricky. Only the filter was not working, but I have used join for the same. Thanks a lot Tricky. Really appreciate. Also I am eagerly looking an answer for a similar kind of a problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472718/spark-1-6-sql-or-dataframe-or-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect_set` over partitioned-by-employee windows to collect distinct `statuses` per employee then pick only result dataset with `statuses` equal to `Array("Continue")`:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 43, "Continue", "John", "3/3/15"),
  (1, 43, "Continue", "John", "3/4/15"),
  (2, 35, "Continue", "Peter", "3/5/15"),
  (3, 32, "Finished", "Alaxender", "3/6/15"),
  (3, 32, "Continue", "Alaxender", "3/7/15"),
  (4, 45, "Continue", "Patrick", "3/8/15"),
  (4, 45, "No Information", "Patrick", "3/9/15")
)toDF("Emp_Id", "Emp_Age", "Emp_Status", "Emp_Name", "Date_Updated")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df.withColumn(
    "Statuses",
    collect_set($"Emp_Status").over(Window.partitionBy($"Emp_Id"))
  ).
  where($"Statuses" === Array("Continue")).
  drop($"Statuses").
  show

// +------+-------+----------+--------+------------+
// |Emp_Id|Emp_Age|Emp_Status|Emp_Name|Date_Updated|
// +------+-------+----------+--------+------------+
// |     1|     43|  Continue|    John|      3/3/15|
// |     1|     43|  Continue|    John|      3/4/15|
// |     2|     35|  Continue|   Peter|      3/5/15|
// +------+-------+----------+--------+------------+
```

[UPDATE]

[UPDATE]

[collect_set()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@collect_set(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) is available in Spark 1.6, but it sounds like the method isn't supported in window operations in that version.  A work-around would be to use `groupBY` followed by `join`:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy($"Emp_Id").agg(collect_set($"Emp_Status").as("Statuses")).
  where($"Statuses" === lit(Array("Continue"))).
  drop($"Statuses")

df.join(df2, Seq("Emp_Id")).show
```

Comment: Unfortunately collect_set function is not working with Spark 1.6. Not sure if there is work around for the same problem. But really appreciate your effort <br>Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'collect_set('status) is not supported in a window operation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Please see a work-around in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Leo C. I am getting an exception on this statement. where($"Statuses" === Array("Continue")). Not sure why it is throwing. Any Idea? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class [Ljava.lang.String; [Ljava.lang.String;@67544105
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:50)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:117)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.$eq$eq$eq(Column.scala:228)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Spark 1.x environment to reproduce the said problem.  I edited my answer to apply `lit()` to the Array-typed column to see if that'll resolve it.