# Spark Data frame 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Data Dump**

```
Work_Id,Assigned_to,Date,Status   
R1,John,3/4/15,Not Started   
R1,John,3/5/15,In Progress        
R1,John,3/6/15,Finished     
R3,Alaxender,3/7/15,In Progress   
R3,Alaxender,3/8/15,In Progress   
R4,Patrick,3/9/15,Finished   
R5,Peter,3/11/15,Finished   
R7,George,3/13/15,Not Started   
R7,George,3/14/15,In Progress   
R8,John,3/15/15,In Progress    
R8,John,3/16/15,In Progress   
R9,Alaxender,3/17/15,Not Started
```

**Final Output**

```
Work_Id,Assigned_to,Date,Status   
R1,John,3/6/15,Finished    
R7,George,3/14/15,In Progress    
R9,Alaxender,3/17/15,Not Started    
R3,Alaxender,3/7/15,In Progress    
R3,Alaxender,3/8/15,In Progress    
R4,Patrick,3/9/15,Finished    
R5,Peter,3/11/15,Finished    
R8,John,3/15/15,In Progress    
R8,John,3/16/15,In Progress
```

There is a datadump same as above which consists of work orders. If there are subsequent request for the same person and the status has "Not started" then the last record(Sort by date) will be qualified. if there is only one record with the status "Not started" then this record will be qualified.

Eg:

```
R1,John,3/4/15,Not Started    
R1,John,3/5/15,In Progress   
R1,John,3/6/15,Finished
```

This record will be qualified

```
R1,John,3/6/15,Finished
```

Rest all the records other than the status has "Not started" for the same person will be qualified in the output.

Any help will be appreciated, to be done this in the Spark 1.6 dataframe using scala.

Comment: How is this any different from the last question you posted with no attempt at a solution yourself? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472718/spark-1-6-sql-or-dataframe-or-windows  ... http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt

Comment: Appreciate your help on this..

Comment: @cricket_007, We would not be able to achieve this with collect_list. Need a different approach altogether.

Comment: Okay, well, still... Can you please [edit] the question with some Scala code that has gotten you part way towards an answer?

Comment: @cricket_007, I have updated an answer here. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Please remove the answer and edit the question

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer, but this is currently degraded the job performance. Is there any better way to do this?

```
val df = myFile.toDF()

val dfFilter = df.filter($"status" === "Not Started")

val dfSelect = dfFilter.select(($"Assigned_to").alias("person"))

val dfInner = dfSelect.join(df, $"person" === $"Assigned_to")

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy($"Assigned_to").orderBy(col("Date").desc)

val dfRank = dfInner.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === "1")

val dfDrop = dfRank.drop($"rank").drop($"person")

val dfLeftOuter = df.join(dfSelect, $"Assigned_to" === $"person", "leftouter")

val nullDf = dfLeftOuter.filter($"person".isNull).drop($"person")

nullDf.unionAll(dfDrop).show
```